# Reduce time complexity from n^3 for following:

Tags: java, xml, algorithm, xml-parsing, time-complexity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Module name="Data">
   <Group name="PAR">
      <HEALTHSTATUS>OK</HEALTHSTATUS>
   </Group>
   <Group name="SYSTEM">
      <Group name="BIOS INFO">
         <VENDOR>HEWLETT-PACKARD</VENDOR>
         <VERSION>J63 V02.55</VERSION>
         <RELEASE_DATE>2/7/2013</RELEASE_DATE>
         <REVISION>2.55</REVISION>
      </Group>
      <Group name="SYSTEM INFO">
         <MANUFACTURER>HEWLETT-PACKARD</MANUFACTURER>
         <PRODUCT_NAME>HP Z820 WORKSTATION</PRODUCT_NAME>
         <SERIAL_NUMBER>2UA6100QHT</SERIAL_NUMBER>
         <FAMILY>103C_53335X G=D</FAMILY>
      </Group>
   </Group>
</Module>
```

I have to extract data, the tag name and value. I have already coded the solution but would like to reduce the time complexity of it from cubic O(n^3).
Can somebody just write a pseudo code or the approach in words ?

**Note:** The elements in the group are not known before handed, hence you can't hardcode them in the xmlObj model with @XmlElement.

**Assumption**: n in the time complexity is the no of groups/sub-groups/other elements. If you don't like it then you may read it as O(l*m*n)

**Desired Output** :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7iIl.png)

Why I have n^3 time complexity?? :
1st loop to iterate through all Groups in the Module.
2nd loop - A group can also have multiple sub-groups, so to iterate through it
3rd loop -  To extract the tag name and tag value in the sub-group.

Comment: What is `n` in your time analysis? Are you assuming that the number of groups, sub-groups and tags are all `O(n)`? What is stopping you from simply scanning the individual lines from top to bottom on by one, retrieving the tags and their values by parsing each line?

Comment: Given the above input, what is your expected output?

Comment: @wookie919 I edited the post to answer to your questions. The elements in group/sub-group are not known before handed i.e. it's dynamic and can be anything, hence I require to iterate and extract data out of it.

Comment: @JonSG I want to traverse in each group and subgroup, get their respective names and also names and value of other elements like MANUFACTURER and its value HP. And print/ load the data in normalized format in db.

Comment: Firstly, show us your code. Then we can see whether we agree with your analysis that it is O(n^3). We can also see whether decent XQuery processors can be expected to optimize the code - there's no point you hand-optimizing it if mainstream XQuery processors optimize it anyway.